# TTS player speaking number in words

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I have a requirement( in Android code) that TTS player should speak out numbers eg "1234" as "one two three four". However currently its speaking it as "one thousand two hundred and thirty four".

Comment: Try adding spaces (1 2 3 4) . It worked for me (and get used to always format the numbers for TTS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TTS does not allow you to specify how the text should be read so your code has to modify the text input so that it reads the individual numbers.

I suggest @opalenzuela's mention that a space in between each number. That should cause the TextToSpeech to read the individual numbers.

If you need some code to help you detect numbers use this:

```
  private boolean isNumber(String word)
 {
boolean isNumber = false;
  try
  {
      Integer.parseInt(word);
      isNumber = true;
   } catch (NumberFormatException e)
  {
       isNumber = false;
  }
  return isNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When targeting API level 21+ (Lollipop), try the new possibilities of [`TtsSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TtsSpan.html):

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("The number is 123456789.");
spannableString.setSpan(new TtsSpan.DigitsBuilder().build(), 14, 22, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
new TextToSpeech(context, null).speak(spannableString, 0, null, null);
```

(not tested)

Comment: Did this work for any one?